# How reliable is an AJAX request that is sent simultaneously on a link click?

Tags: events, jquery, hyperlink

We have a web shop written in PHP. On a category page we want to integrate a 3rd party click tracker: Each time an article gets clicked, we need to send an AJAX request to our server which in turn will send a REST request to the 3rd party tracking server.

So say our product links look like

```
<a href="product.php?id=1234" class="product" data-id="123">Product A</a>
```

To be safe, we would wait for the tracking request to complete, before we redirect the browser to the product URL.

```js
$('a.product').on('click',function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var a = $(this);
    $.getJSON(trackingUrl, {id:a.data('id')}, function(d) {
        window.location.href = a.attr('href');
    });
});
```

This has the obvious disadvantage, that there's a delay after a product click as the browser has to wait for the AJAX request to complete.

So we thought about a fire-and-forget approach, where we don't wait for the response of the AJAX request:

```js
$('a.product').on('click',function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var a = $(this);
    $.getJSON(trackingUrl, {id:a.data('id')});
    window.location.href = a.attr('href');
});
```

We don't wait for a successful response here and hope that the browser will complete our request anyway, even if we leave the current page immediately after we sent the AJAX request.

Is it safe to assume that the request will be completed even if the browser already has left the originating page?

Comment: Why not just call `e.preventDefault()` using your first example but move the redirect outside the AJAX post line (not waiting for it to complete). That way, it **has** to fire first.

Comment: Thanks, i'll update the question. But still i wonder, if that request is really completed, even if the browser has already loaded the new page.

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you click on the "a" tag, browser will send the request but its a very low probability that your request will be completed. Sometimes the request takes quite a while on different internet speed and also traffic on the server. So it is highly not recommended to take this approach.

If the browser is redirected to a URL before the request gets completed then its a 50% chance that actually request has been made to the server. If the request has been made before redirection happens then your work is done because the response is not necessary but if not then browser discard that request and stops it.

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask more.